# How to check terminal command links to where or which file?

Tags: command-line

For example, if I type `lua` in my terminal it opens lua. But can I check where it links to? I have different version of lua in my linux ubuntu 14.04 OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `readlink` . From `man readlink`

> readlink - print resolved symbolic links or canonical file names

Example, `x-terminal-emulator` is a link to `/etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator`, which finally links to your default terminal emulator in `/usr/bin`. Here i am using `-e` flag to check for existing files.

```
$> which x-terminal-emulator                                                   
/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator
$> readlink -e $(which x-terminal-emulator)                                    
/usr/bin/sakura

$> readlink -e $(which python)                                                 
/usr/bin/python2.7
```

The same can be done with `realpath` command:

```
$> realpath $(which x-terminal-emulator) 
/usr/bin/sakura
```

Answer (score 2):

type

```
which lua
```

from man which:

which - shows the full path of (shell) commands.

E.g.

```
which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: `which` doesn't resolve symbolic links. Refer to my answer